# What is the search keyword for 'two enum members ORed together' usage?

Tags: c#

what kind of usage? i don't know it's custom name. what can i write on google to search below kind of codes...

```
service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.EwsRequest | TraceFlags.EwsResponse;
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 6):

You use it as Flags. You should tag the enum declaration of the enum with the [Flags] Attribute. And use powers of two as the named values, so binary and and binary allow you to manipulate the bitflags.

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
  None=0,
  A=1,
  B=2,
  C=4,
  D=8
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(VS.71).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx

Or if misunderstood your question and you just wanted to know what flags there are in TraceFlags then just use Go to definition in visual studio.

Comment: The [Flags] attrib is not important, only affects ToString(). The 2^N numbering is most relevant.

Comment: Change the example to `Colors` is much more easier for OP to understand.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - Very no. Expressing your intent is paramount, and additionally VB does not supoort bitwise operations on non-flags so it raises portability concerns. Basically there is no good reason not to use the attribute.

Comment: @anna, OK, I didn't know about the VB angle, and I agree on the intent. But for C# the effect is minimal.

Comment: @Danny Chen I don't think Colors are a good example for a Flags-Enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a single trace flag, or you can specify multiple trace flags by combining them with a logical OR.

And this is a logical OR combination you are demonstrating here.